# Logistic Regression using Non Numeric data

Tags: r, logistic, classification, predictive-models

I am trying to understand how logistic regression can use multiple variables to predict an outcome that is non-numeric. For example I have a titanic data set with 14 variables, 4 variables are strings, 4 are numeric, 2 are ints, and 4 are categorical factors. Now I use the built in logistic regression model in R to predict Surviving passengers (0 or 1 factor):

```
lr_model <- glm(Survived ~ int variable + categorical variable + ... different types of variables, data=trainData)
```

But when I predict on the new data .. I get numeric values returned, not 1,0 predictions like the Survived predictor should have modeled it. If I could get an explaination of how the model works on numeric and non numeric data that would clear things up, and if it does spit out numeric values, should I just write a function to see if it is higher than 0.5 to see if a given observation is Survived, and below 0.5 as they didn't survive?

Any thoughts?

https://github.com/conradbm/data_science/blob/master/titanic_dataset/hw3/hw3_bmconrad.R

Answer (score 2):

Logistic regression predicts on odd-ratios or probability of success. In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Logistic_function.2C_odds.2C_odds_ratio.2C_and_logit):

> ... whereas the output always takes values between zero and one

To predict 0 or 1, you will need to decide a threshold such as 0.5. If you try different thresholds, you may draw a ROC curve where you can decide your optimal threshold based on your preference on sensitivity and specificity.

Comment: +1. I'd add that the fact that logistic regression returns a probability -- which is often well-calibrated meaning is actually is a probability -- is very useful.

Comment: @Wayne Yeah. I wrote "... or probability of success ....". It's actually the log-odds, but it can be converted.

Comment: Right, I'm just emphasizing that this is much more useful than something that just returned a 1 or 0 or some kind of ranking or something else. The OP is gaining more than they realize.

Comment: @Student T -- If the logistic regression returns values above the 0,1 threshold, such as -2.34, 2.44, ect... Is this an error on my part when building the model, or is this also a part of the logistic regression model?

Comment: @bmc As I show from wikipedia, logistic regression always output between zero and one. It's a binary prediction algorithm.

Comment: @Student T It seems like it is returning a probability, at least for the R function glm. By using the round function, it actually gave me the results I was looking for: df_test$Survived <- round(predict(model, df_test, type="response"))

Comment: @bmc `round` is simply putting a 0.5 threshold. You may want to do that if you want your threshold be 0.5.

Comment: @Student T good point, `round` just does a 0.5 threshold, would it require ah home-made function to change that threshold?

Comment: @bmc: Be careful what prediction value you expect.You want `type="response"` and I believe the default is `type="link"` which will give values outside of [0,1]. See `?predict.glm`